# Best way to search between multiple large list python

Tags: python, dataframe, search

BG: All the data come from database, I have passed it to pandas DataFrame. I have created id by joining multiple unique columns together. 

The end goal is to do string concatenation on the main_list. for example

`1. id
 2. item (item2 = item_group = item_name = item_value,item_name2 = item_value2, item3 = item_name = item_value)`

I have tried a linear search but the performance is really poor with ~100k records for each list.

So I have a main list that contains a set of item

`1. id
 2. item (this is my item to search,item2,item3,item4)`

the **search list A**/item_group list contains (so I will try to match the item_group first to see if it exists in the current list) **Issues with the search list A is that an item_group can contain multiples item_name so matching the item_group, I need the item_name values so that I can search in search list B**

`1. item_group
 2. item_name
 3. id`

the **search list B** can be called a sub_item list contains (then i will match the item_name to see if it exists here)

`1. item_name
 2. item_value
 3. id`

**Methods Tried**

> Trying to create a dicts based on the 2nd list to efficiently search but was still having performance issues took very long time to just populate the dict
>   Thinking of doing joins

**From the image, joining based on ID won't really work because 1 id can contain multiples item**
[image]

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected output from this data?

Comment: added some sample data for you

Comment: The sample data you added is pretty messy, I can't understand it.  Can you provide actual runnable Python code which creates at least two sample rows of your DataFrame, and explain to us what you are trying to achieve at a higher level?

Comment: You say that the data comes from a database. Many databases are great at speeding up requests with well designed indexes. Could it be an option here?